# Why can't I normalize this random unicode string?

Tags: python, unicode, normalization, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I need to evaluate levenshtein edit distance on unicode strings, which means that two strings containing identical content will need to be normalized to avoid biasing the edit distance.

Here is how I generate random unicode strings for my tests:

```
def random_unicode(length=10):
    ru = lambda: unichr(random.randint(0, 0x10ffff))
    return ''.join([ru() for _ in xrange(length)])
```

And here is the simple test case that is failing:

```
import unicodedata
uni = random_unicode()
unicodedata.normalize(uni, 'NFD')
```

And here is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I checked to make sure that `uni` was, indeed, a unicode object:

```
u'\U00020d93\U000fb2e6\U0005709a\U000bc31e\U00080262\U00034f00\U00059941\U0002dd09\U00074f6d\U0009ef7a'
```

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The input arguments appear reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've switched the parameters of `normalize`. From [the relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

> `unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr)`
>
> Return the normal form *form* for the Unicode string * unistr*. Valid values for *form* are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.

The *first* argument is the form, and the *second* is the string to be normalized. This works just fine:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFD', uni)
```

Comment: ... I am an idiot.  Thank you!  There really should be an assertion error or something to explicitly point out that the first parameter expects a unicode string =/  "what can go wrong will go wrong" as they say...

Comment: funny that python doesn't tell you that the parameter one is not a valid normal form...